# Double integrals and interchangeable limits

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why do the answers come out to be different in these two cases where only the integrating order has been changed (The first one comes out to be 0.5 and the other one come out to be -0.5). We have learnt that the limits are interchangeable when the limits are constants. This is a little contradicting.:

[image: Image here]

P.S. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: It's very much analogous to changing the sum of a conditionally convergent series by permuting its terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the limits are interchangeable when the limits are constants

Conditions apply to this statement (look up the actual theorem in your book; they should be there). One of those conditions is that the integrals involved should be *proper*. Your integral is not proper (as the function diverges as we move toward the origin), and therefore strange things may happen in places you didn't expect them to.

Comment: So why the absolute rule "Order of integration does not change the final result provided the limits are constant and are changed accordingly"? These are the exact words in my textbook and also mentioned in many other lectures. Isn't that misleading?

Comment: Clearly they are misleading, as this example so neatly shows. You knew that already before posting this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up Arthur. Have a nice day.I just came across the two theorems for the interchangeable limits and changing the order of integration. Thank you again.